# Как вывести список из объектов на экран

Tags: python, python-2.x

В наличии есть список состоящий из объектов класса. Нужно вывести этот массив на экран чтобы он был читабельный.

```
class Database:
    name = 'n/a'
    phone = 'n/a'
    list = []
    copy_list = []

    class Rec:
        def __init__(self, nam, phon):
            self.name = nam
            self.phone = phon

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s is a %s" % (self.name, self.phone)

    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.my_file = open(fileName, 'a+')
        self._load()

    def addRecord(self):
        self.list.append(Database.Rec(self.name, self.phone))

    def out(self):
        print('\n'.join(self.list))
```

Comment: У вас уже есть метод `out`, насколько я понимаю он как раз предназначен для вывода списка объектов внутри объекта `Database`. Он вам не подходит?

Comment: Он мне то подходит но на экран выводится вот такое: [<__main__.Rec instance at 0x020F2B70>]

Comment: Кстати, у вас какая все-таки версия Python? Стоит метка для Python 2, а функция `print` как в Python 3.

Comment: Python версия 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[<__main__.Rec instance at 0x020F2B70>]` можно получить только если напрямую через `print` выводить содержимое `Database.list`. Если выводить через метод `Database.out()`, то получим ошибку

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Rec found
```

Чтобы такой ошибки не было, до выполнения `join` нужно явно привести все элементы к строкам. С учетом этого и некоторых других поправок (в том числе убрал чтение из файла, суть от этого не поменялась), у меня получилось вот что:

```
class Database:
    class Rec:
        def __init__(self, nam, phon):
            self.name = nam
            self.phone = phon

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s is a %s" % (self.name, self.phone)

    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
        self.copy_list = []

    def addRecord(self, name, phone):
        self.list.append(Database.Rec(name, phone))

    def out(self):
        print '\n'.join(str(item) for item in self.list)

d = Database()
d.addRecord('Alice', 1111)
d.addRecord('Bob', 22222)
d.out()
```

Вывод:

```
Alice is a 1111
Bob is a 22222
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить в класс метод:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join(str(item) for item in self.list)
```

и выводить результат через print

```
print database
```